# Samba fails to add a user entry, how do I fix this?

Tags: samba

I was configuring Samba and tried to add a domain user, but it returns this:

```
failed to add entry for the user student
```

These are the commands I've done so far:

```
frigate@frigate-desktop:~$ su 
Password: 
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# nano /etc/samba/smb.conf 
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# groupadd -g 201 machines
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# mkdir -m 0775 /home/ntlogon
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# mkdir /home/samba /home/samba/profiles
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# chmod 1755 /home/samba/profiles/
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# useradd -m test
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# passwd test
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# smbpasswd -a test
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Added user test.
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# smbpasswd -a root
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Added user root.
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# smbpasswd -a student
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Failed to add entry for user student.
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# smbpasswd -a student
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Failed to add entry for user student.
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# smbpasswd -a stu
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Mismatch - password unchanged.
Unable to get new password.
root@frigate-desktop:/home/frigate# smbpasswd -a stu
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Failed to add entry for user stu.
```

How can I add this user to Samba?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to create a UNIX user named student before you create a samba user named student.

Comment: And how to do that? The answer is incomplete.

Comment: In my experience this answer is correct. A user name is added in Linux with ```sudo useradd student``` and Unix with ```sudo adduser student```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you did not create it yet. So to add it for the first time to samba need to add the

```
-a
```

option

```
sudo smbpasswd -a test
```

A samba user is setted and added in a different way than unix users. That means that **not because a unix user exists, a samba user exists**. The way to add a samba user is setting its password from unix user

Comment: This actually helped me. There are circumstances where a Unix user can exist and still result in the error. Thanks.

Comment: beware, it is not because a unix user exists that it exists into the world of samba!

Comment: By my count he used the add command (-a) six times, so the "Maybe you did not create it yet" indicates an inadequate reading of the question.

Comment: @cedwin I answered the question to a more general matter, not only specific so it helps other users as well and seems it did